# Using Resharpers testrunner in script?

Tags: parallel-processing, nunit, resharper, command-line-interface

We want to parallelize our unittests, however the nunit-console.exe cannot do this out of the box. And the NUnit.MultiCore project on codeplex.com seems to fail loading our custom log4net appenders - probably AppDomain error in the framework.

However, Resharpers own test runner, runs nunit tests parallel pr. assembly and my question is whether is it possible to use Resharpers unit test runner, JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.exe,  as a CLI tool and run this on our build server?

Comment: Just a suggestion. Can [PNunit](http://www.plasticscm.com/infocenter/technical-articles/pnunit.aspx) be suitable here?